# Linq lambda Select statement

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am new to this, I want to select : (SQL) select textfileURL from [tablename];

What I have now :

```
public string GetfileURL()
    {
         return context.wordpuzzles.Select(i => i.textfileURL).ToString();
    }
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: `Select` returns an `IEnumerable<>` which you are casting to `string`.

Comment: This returns multiple urls, which one do you want?

Comment: ERROR : Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line :

```
context.wordpuzzles.Select(i => i.textfileURL)
```

Will return a IEnumerable. Then you trying to cast this to a string.
I think you want to assign all texts in this IEnumerable to a string?

Then [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx) can come in handy =).

```
context.wordpuzzles.Select(i => i.textfileURL)
              .Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, c) => current + c + "\n");
```

Will result in this :

> string1
>   string2
>   etc.

Not sure if this is what you really want...

If you just want one you can use [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx).

Example :

```
context.wordpuzzles.FirstOrDefault(i => i.textfileURL.Contains("your criteria"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get your item(s) correct first so try one of these:

```
public string GetfileURL()
{
     return context.wordpuzzles.Single(i => i.condition = "yourCriteria").textfileURL.ToString();
}
```

or

```
public string GetfileURL()
{
     return context.wordpuzzles.First(i => i.condition  = "yourCriteria").textfileURL.ToString();
}
```

or

```
public string GetfileURL()
{
     dim results = context.wordpuzzles.Where(i => i.condition  = "yourCriteria").ToList();

     'perform rest of code
}
```

But you gotto make sure if you perform the Single call it only has 1 row in the return statement.

If you are not sure you have any rows you can add .SingleOrDefault or .FirstOrDefault

Answer (score 1):

You are doing almost correct thing, but if you want to select one result - use [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx). Otherwise you'll get [`IEnumerable<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) projects each element of a sequence into a new form. So it returns `IEnumerable` and not a string only.